# MVC4 IEnumerable model binding always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the code below my IEnumerable bookedRooms always have null values when they reach the controller, it knows how many bookedRooms I sent back but the values of RoomID and NumRooms are always null for each of the items any ideas?

I have the following view model...

```
public class SelectDatesViewModel

    public int venueID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookedRoomViewModel> bookedRooms {get;set;}
    public string checkInDateString { get; set; }
    public int pageNo { get; set; }
    public bool showCheckIn { get; set;}
    public string startDateString { get; set; }
}
public class BookedRoomViewModel
{
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
    public string NumRooms { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following jquery ajax call..

```
function showArrivalCalendar() {
    showThrobber();
    var info = {
        venueID: venueID,
        bookedRooms: getBookedRooms(),
        startDateString: $("#calendarHolder").data("arrivalstartdate"),
        checkInDateString: "",
        pageNo: 1,
        showCheckIn: true
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Booking/BookingCalendar/",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (retValue) {
            $("#calendarHolder").html(data);
            hideThrobber();
        }
    });
}
function getBookedRooms() {
    var bookedRooms = [];
    $("#selectBookingType").find("select").each(function () {
         if ($(this).find(":selected").val() > 0) {
            var noRooms = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            bookedRooms.push({
                    RoomID: $(this).data("roomid"),
                    NumRooms: noRooms
            });
        };
    });
    return bookedRooms;
}
```

To post to this controller..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BookingCalendar(SelectDatesViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView(GetBookingDates(model.venueID, model.startDateString, model.showCheckIn, model.pageNo, model.checkInDateString));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call options are wrong: `dataType` is for specifying the type of data that you're expecting back from the server not the type of the data what you send to the server.

You need to set the `contentType` property (see [JQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to `"application/json"` if you want to send JSON data and want the model binder working correctly (you may also need to `JSON.stringify` the data)

So the correct usage:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Booking/BookingCalendar/",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(info),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (retValue) {
        $("#calendarHolder").html(data);
        hideThrobber();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good call, that worked but I had to JSON.stringify(info)(I updated the 1st post).thanks nemesv